# Change site logo for different languages

Tags: i18n-l10n

I do believe that should be popular issue but I can't find any questions here about this: is there any way to make site's logo different for different languages? I've found some threads regarding this thing in drupal.org forums, but these solutions are not working for me...

p.s. I am using D7 and currently working on Fusion subtheme Acquia Marina (if it helps)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Internationalization module](http://drupal.org/project/i18n), after installing and enabling the modules, you can activate it at admin/config/regional/i18n/variable, look for 'theme settings'

Comment: Great, thank you - It appeared so simple, some of the threads in Drupal.org forums should be closed as it is misleadingly telling that this issue is not yet solved.

Comment: This is a gr8 hint. Saved hours...:)

Comment: And remember to install and activate: Variable, Variable store, Variable realm modules and Variable translation.

Answer (score 0):

For non-coders:  You switch to the language in the admin section, per:

https://www.drupal.org/node/313272#comment-1091779